# Why my file content change when i Get it?

Tags: angular, file, http

I want to get a binary file who are in my asset folder :

```
this.http.get('../../../assets/files/CarteLoraWan.maj', { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe((content) => {
  console.log(this.stringToBytes(content));
})

public stringToBytes(string) {
      var array = new Uint8Array(string.length);
      for (var i = 0, l = string.length; i < l; i++) {
          array[i] = string.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      return array.buffer;
    }
```

The probleme is that my file (when i open it on my computer) start by :

`494e4e4fece802003e6f83b0000000004c4f5241010000000000000000000000f0`

The result of my function start by :

`494e4e4ffdfd02003e6ffdfd000000004c4f5241010000000000000000000000fd`

What is wrong in my code to transform the content file ?

Thanks

**EDIT** : Add subscribe content + stringToBytes function.

Comment: In the `subscribe` you **only** do a `console.log`?

Comment: @CristianTraìna i edit my post ;)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it could be a cache. You might want to clear the browser cache.